# Layer symbology is not applied in layer to KMZ

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, kml, symbology

I have created a tool in modelbuilder. I use the make feature layer tool to create my layer.
I right click on the layer and select a symbology.
I run my tool and I can see that my symbology is applied on my layer correctly, when using add to display.

However the resulting kmz does not contain the symbology of the layer. 
Does anybody know how  can I involve the symbology in my kmz ?

The symbology Is simple arcgis symbols like cirles , triangles etc. 
the "InputFeatures_JSONToFeatures(2)" parameter in the model below contains the correnct symbology.
However the kml contains a default one like no symbology has been applied.

part of my tool is shown in the following image :
(Arcgis 10.2.2)

[image]

Comment: I've just tested this and it worked for me, a single polygon. The layer file that I set the symbology of the output of make featurelayer was a full path (so not relative), just an idea?

Comment: @Hornbydd Could you please place a print screen of your tool? The fact with my tool is that the layer input DOES HAVE a symbology, but it is not packaged in the kmz file. I am using point geometries ,

Comment: Honestly my model was nothing more than a make feature layer linking to layer to KML, so what you are showing above. Why don't you try that in a new model, to test it and then try some simple symbology, if that works then it would suggest that the symbology is causing the problem, maybe to fancy for KML?

Comment: Isn't it possible to right click on the resulting kmz and point it to the layer you want to dub the symbology from?

Answer (score 1):

I also face with this problem, and I managed to solve it by using the "Apply Symbology From Layer" tool between the "Make Feature Layer" tool and the "Layer To KML" tool. Right clicking the "Make Feature Layer" output and setting symbology did not work in this case (using the "Layer To KML" tool).